# Instead of mutex i want to use semphore in fibocom G500 GL modem

Tags: c

Actually i am going through Quectel Modem.  whatever the  mutex function present in quectel code. that function i dont want to use in FIBOCOM modem code.Due to mutex mechanism is not supportable for FIBOCOM MODEM... so insted of mutex i have to use semaphore..can you guys please help.

as per the fibocom functionality i am trying to modified my quectel code.

```
Ql_osTakeMutex(Mutex.GeneralConf);
if(Ql_FileCheck((u8 *)GENERAL_CONFIG_FILE) != QL_RET_OK)
{
    Ql_DebugTrace("First time Loading Gen Config  \n");
    Ql_osGiveMutex(Mutex.GeneralConf);
    WriteGeneralConfig(DEFAULT_PARA);   
    Ql_osTakeMutex(Mutex.GeneralConf);
}
```

i want only solution of mutex...

Comment: What variety of semaphore do you want to use?  C11 semaphores are available only if the C implementation you're using supports C11, which many implementations for embedded devices do not.  I can name at least three other semaphore flavors off the top of my head, but which, if any, are available to you is implementation dependent.

Comment: More generally, yes, it should be possible to use semaphores in place of mutexes, but it is unclear what you want to know about doing so.

Comment: or can u suggest me ..can i use..both semaphore and mutex mechanism in one source file.

Comment: In general, a semaphore can be used like a  non-reentrant mutex by initializing the semaphore count to 1. Locking the mutex is equivalent to waiting for the semaphore count to be greater than 0 and then decrementing it. Unlocking the mutex is equivalent to incrementing the semaphore count and signalling other threads when it is greater than 0. For a re-entrant mutex, you are also allowed to lock the mutex (and decrement the semaphore count, possibly below 0) if you are the current owner of the mutex.